# Python regex to select spaces not between round brackets

Tags: python, regex

I want to split my log data as shown (split with spaces outside round brackets):

```
['2017-04-21T02:30:01+00:00 qvidbbdpgr11 CROND[12321]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)']

[['2017-04-21T02:30:01+00:00',
'qvidbbdpgr11',
'CROND[12321]:',
'(root)',
'CMD',
'(/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)']]
```

I've tried this :

```
(\(.+?\))|\s
```

but it gives me this :

```
[['2017-04-21T02:30:01+00:00',
None,
'qvidbbdpgr11',
None,
'CROND[12321]:',
None,
'',
'(root)',
'',
None,
'CMD',
None,
'',
'(/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)',
'']]
```

I've seen a lot of topics about this kind of regex but since i'm not familiar with it I don't really understand how to adapt it to do want I want...

Thank you very much